# Android: creating dynamic layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a dynamic horizontal layout which have 3 views which take equal space on screen. When 1 view is hidden then remaining views should fill up its space.

**I am trying to achieve this using xml and not considering to write some code for it.**

I am able to get 3 views to take equal space to fill the screen by using `LinearLayout` and weight but not able make it so that view should fill the space if some views are hidden.

My layout looks like this.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is bob" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is bob" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is bob" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I thought it must be already asked by someone but i am not able to find any relevant question.

Comment: whats the error?????????

Comment: make visibility of First TextView as View.INVISIBLE

Comment: @Vijay: When i hide 1 TextView. Remaining 2 TextViews cover 66%  and 33% space is empty. i want to Take 50% space by each textView so that 100% is filled by remaining 2

Comment: You should remove weightsum. Check answer given by readyanderoid, if it works for you accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

and remove

```
android:weightSum="3"
```

from main layout it will work.

Your layout should be like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is bob" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is bob" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is bob" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It was in back of my head and I already had done this but  at the very moment but was not able to remember. Thats perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Use databinding for changing android:weightSum attribute in container when view's visibility is set to GONE. see docs: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html.
You'll have to create one model object anyways.